# mod_rewrite / .htaccess - domain name showing twice in URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an "addon domain" with no specified htaccess file but the main site (of which the add on site is a sub dir) DOES have htaccess which rewrites url to remove the .html prefix.

Anyhow when i go to the addon domain for instance: test.com/about.html it automatically changes to test.com/test.com/about.html

Can anyone point me in the direction to correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no htaccess file with modRewrite in it in a directory, apache goes up to the parent directory to search for it, and this goes up along the tree (this is not affected by having an addon domain or not). So that means that your addon domain is affected by the htaccess file of the parent domain.

What you need to do is create an htaccess file in the subdirectory (the addon domain) and desactivate rewriting :

```
RewriteEngine Off
```

Or you can add your own RewriteRules if you want.